# nodejs keycloak-connect-graphql not working while in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, graphql, keycloak, keycloak-connect

I have hit an issue that I have struggled to figure out for the last little while regarding docker. Here is a shortened version of the story

In my development environment (everything is running on localhost), code works great, whenever I add my authorization token in my headers keycloak-connect detects it and works as usual. The problem occurs when I use it in docker and add custom network interfaces.

When the docker container boots up, I have it connect to keycloak via http://keycloak:8080/auth and generate the realm. That works fine, not an issue, thus I know that the keycloak network is up and running as expected. I am able to remote into the container, communicate with keycloak, get a token and etc...

In my graphql application, I use keycloak-connect-graphql to set the context of the graphql application which in turn uses keycloak-connect to set up all the headers. The problem is, that keycloak-connect-graphql tells me that there is no header.If I simply print out the request, I can clearly tell that there is a token being passed in, it's just that for some reason, keycloak-connect-graphql/keycloak-connect does not want to set it because I am using a different network besides localhost.

I was actually able to side-step this problem in production by setting the keycloak url to be a the public url (https://keycloak.DOMAINNAME.com) which makes absolutely no sense to me because http://keycloak:8080/auth does not work. I have digged through keycloak-connect and the keycloak-connect-graphql code and I could not find anything relating to a CORS issue or something else suspicious. If anyone has any ideas please let me know. This bug has been driving me crazy.

Code snippet:
keycloak configuration (app.config)

```
  keycloak: {
    realm: process.env.KEYCLOAK_REALM,
    'auth-server-url': 'http://keycloak:8080/auth',
    'ssl-required': 'none',
    resource: process.env.KEYCLOAK_RESOURCE,
    'public-client': true,
    'use-resource-role-mappings': true,
    'confidential-port': 0,
  },
```

configurekeycloak.js

```
function configureKeycloak(app, graphqlPath) {
  const keycloakConfig = require('../config/app.config').keycloak;

  const memoryStore = new session.MemoryStore();

  app.use(
    session({
      secret:
        process.env.SESSION_SECRET_STRING || 'this should be a long secret',
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      store: memoryStore,
    }),
  );

  const keycloak = new Keycloak(
    {
      store: memoryStore,
    },
    keycloakConfig,
  );

  // Install general keycloak middleware
  app.use(
    keycloak.middleware({
      admin: graphqlPath,
    }),
  );

  // Protect the main route for all graphql services
  // Disable unauthenticated access
  app.use(graphqlPath, keycloak.middleware());

  return { keycloak };
}
```

index.js

```
// perform the standard keycloak-connect middleware setup on our app
const { keycloak } = configureKeycloak(app, graphqlPath);

// Ensure entire GraphQL Api can only be accessed by authenticated users
app.use(playgroundPath, keycloak.protect());

const server = new ApolloServer({
  gateway,
  // uploads: false,

  // Apollo Graph Manager (previously known as Apollo Engine)
  // When enabled and an `ENGINE_API_KEY` is set in the environment,
  // provides metrics, schema management and trace reporting.
  engine: false,

  // Subscriptions are unsupported but planned for a future Gateway version.
  subscriptions: false,

  // Disable default playground
  playground: true,

  context: ({ req }) => {
    return {
      kauth: new KeycloakContext({ req }),
    };
  },

  // Tracing must be enabled for this plugin to add the headers
  tracing: true,
  // Register the plugin
  plugins: [ServerTimingPlugin],
});
```

Edit:
setting network_mode to host fixes the issue, but I much prefer using dockers integrated networks rather than using network_mode host, especially for production

Edit 2:
I was able to reproduce the error in my local development environment (without shelling into docker and then debugging from there). I was able to do this buy using the IP address provided by docker. This yields the same results. I have narrowed the issue down to keycloak-connect, which for some reason, does no want to connect to keycloak or something. Still not sure

Comment: `ping keycloak` from node.js? does this server know what `keycloak` is, resolves properly this name to IP? use IP in config? docker-compose file?

Comment: @xadm yeah I used necat and the server says its open. Also Keycloak admin (another nodejs module) works without a problem. Its just the keycloak adapter. Doing a bit more research it seems to be a bug on their end. Ill leave this question open for now as maybe someone else experienced the same issue and nows a workaround